# How can I get chmod -R to work for me? (operation not permitted)

Tags: terminal, osx-snow-leopard

When I try to do something like:

```
chmod -R ug+rw files
```

On a folder with existing content I get:

chmod: Unable to change file mode on [fill in the blank]: Operation not permitted.

It's on a site on my own computer (which I am the admin of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `sudo chmod -R ug+rw files`.  You have to be the owner of all of the files to change the permissions, unless you're operating with root privileges.

Comment: Thanks! Helps. I also have to do this with SSH on shared hosting...with a Linux server, do you know what the equivalent of sudo is by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

On my mac I found I needed to run this:

```
chflags -R nouchg /path/to/folder
```